# S4 Programming Error in .local(.Object...)

Tags: r, r-s4

I have made all my functions into generics and methods on their respective classes.
But now what worked as functions no longer works.

Class `bond.id` has no generic or methods.
It only holds variables that are passed to `a`, `b`, and `c`, each of these all call `bond.id@...`

Fine no problem `a`, `b`, and `c` work as they are supposed to using `new(" ",...)`

When everything was a function and not a method on a class the last step was a `class(z)` that inherited `a`, `b`, and `c`.
This worked.
But now when I `setClass("z", contains = c(a, b, c))` I get the following error:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
> argument "bond.id" is missing, with no default

I am a little perplexed if `a`, `b`, `c` are working why is the `setClass` for `z` behaving this way?

Comment: Please provide a [small but complete reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I wish I could but then I would have to create five classes, three generics, three methods, and a datafile object.  I think I may just give up.  Every turn in R presents and obstacle.  Maybe there is a better language to do this.

Comment: It seems a simple error to me, you simply forgot to specify a necessary argument called `bond.id` somewhere... but it's really hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: BTW you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to post long pieces of code...

Comment: That's what I thought but each method works on its own.               The error occurs when I try to create a class that contains each class.  setClass("BondAnalytics", contains = c("BondDetails", BondCashFlows")) I get the error and when I traceback it goes to:function (.Object, bond.id, principal, settlement.date, price) 
    {
        library(lubridate)
        issue.date = as.Date(bond.id@IssueDate, "%m-%d-%Y")
        start.date = as.Date(bond.id@DatedDate, "%m-%d-%Y")           This all worked fine until I created generics and methods on the classes.  Oh well...